# Thread is not getting stopped while polling using camel file poller

Tags: java, timer, tomcat7, apache-camel

I am trying to implement simple file polling from one folder to another using camel 2.14 version. I have used pollEnrich with basic timer to poll every 30 seconds. But whenever I tried to stop the tomcat 7.0 server I am getting the logs as:

**Catalina.logs**

```
SEVERE: The web application [/CamelPoller] appears to have started a thread named [Camel (camel-1) thread #0 - timer://myTimer] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Aug 14, 2015 2:50:06 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/CamelPoller] appears to have started a thread named [Camel (camel-1) thread #1 - file://D:/Input] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
```

**FilePollerDemo.java**

```
public class FilePollerDemo {

    public FilePollerDemo() {
        CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext();
        try {
            context.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
                public void configure() {
                from("timer://myTimer?period=30000")
                    .pollEnrich("file://D:/Input?fileName=test.txt")
                    .to("file://D:/Output");
                }
            });
            context.start();
//          context.stop();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

I have commented out the `context.stop()`, because if I am using it, the file polling is not happening or if I used like this :

```
context.start();
thread.sleep(30000);
context.stop();
```

then the poller run only for once.
Please help me I am new to camel.

Comment: If you want your context to run longer (standalone), you can look at the example here: http://camel.apache.org/running-camel-standalone-and-have-it-keep-running.html